# How do I get `__FILE__` when sourcing a csh script

Tags: csh, tcsh

I have a script that is used to set some env vars in the calling csh shell. Some of those variables depend on the location of the script.

If the file is a proper csh script, I can use $0 to access `__FILE__` but if I run the script using source, it just tells me csh or tcsh.

Since I'm using this to set vars in the parent shell, I have to use source.

What to do?

Comment: Also see https://serverfault.com/questions/139285/tcsh-path-of-sourced-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you access `$_` on the first line of the file, it will contain the name of the file if it's sourced. If it's run directly then `$0` will contain the name.

```
#!/bin/tcsh
set called=($_)
if ($called[2] != "") echo "Sourced: $called[2]"
if ($0 != "tcsh") echo "Called: $0"
```

Comment: That is easy to break:

If you chain commands with ";", then called will return the wrong info.

`echo HELLO; source test.csh`
`HELLO`
`Sourced: HELLO;`
`Called: /bin/tcsh`
`

Comment: @engtech: That's because `$_` really "Substitutes the command line of the last command executed."

Answer (score 2):

This is hard to read, but is actually works:

If your script is named test.csh

`/usr/sbin/lsof +p $$ | \grep -oE /.\*test.csh`

Comment: I like this better than the accepted answer. Using $\_ _only_ works if you can tightly control exactly how the script is sourced.

Comment: What does the lsof option *+p* do? I think the option should be *-p* to select the process number of the parent shell, so `/usr/sbin/lsof -p $$ | grep -oE /.\*test.csh`. https://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof

Answer (score 1):

[this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/139553/526886) describes how `lsof` and a bit of grep magic is the only thing that seems to stand a chance of working for nested sourced files under csh/tcsh.

If your script is named `source_me.tcsh`:

```
/usr/sbin/lsof -p $$ | grep -oE '/.*source_me\.tcsh'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$$` does not work when one calls the source within a sub-shell. `BASH_PID` only works in bash.

```
% (sleep 1; source source_me.csh)
```

I found the following works a bit better:

```
% set pid=`cut -d' ' -f4 < /proc/self/stat`
% set file=`/usr/sbin/lsof +p $pid|grep -m1 -P '\s\d+r\s+REG\s' | xargs | cut -d' ' -f9`
```

First line finds the pid of the current process that is sourcing the file. This came from [Why is $$ returning the same id as the parent process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21063765/why-is-returning-the-same-id-as-the-parent-process/21063837#21063837). The second line finds the first (and hopefully only) FD opened for read of a regular file. This came from engtech above.