# Get script path when executing it in C Shell

Tags: shell, unix, csh

I have script suppose env.csh . I can source it from  any where irrespective of its location

```
      File Path :  /tmp/dump/env.csh 

      Run Path : /usr  

      Command :  source /tmp/dump/env.csh
```

How to get file path when I am sourcing env.csh from / folder usr .

I used this script

```
  set SCRIPT=`readlink -f "$0"`
  set SCRIPTPATH=`dirname "$SCRIPT"`
  echo $SCRIPTPATH
```

But It is gives path as /usr

Any way to get file path

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, could you please clarify what you mean by "sourcing env.csh", are you referring to "source env.csh"?

Comment: Yes its source env.csh

Comment: In that case, see:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4650/determining-path-to-sourced-shell-script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 set called=($_)
 set script_fn=`readlink -f $called[2]`
 echo $script_fn
 set script_dir = `dirname "$script_fn"`
 echo $script_dir
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file is named `env.csh`

```
set scriptpath=`find /proc/$$/fd -type l -lname '*env.csh' -printf '%l' + | xargs dirname`
echo $scriptpath
```

See also [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/139285/tcsh-path-of-sourced-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337925/how-do-i-get-file-when-sourcing-a-csh-script/16283115#comment115921289_16283115).